# Can I leave one side of my metal frame dry half wall open for appliance ventilation?

Tags: drywall, ventilation, metal

I am installing an indoor metal frame half wall that will hold a countertop in a bar. The The wall is L shaped and anchored on concrete and against a wall at the top of the 'L'. The long part of the 'L' is 270cm and short side 55cm. Height 110cm.

The counter top is wood covered in copper sheet and weighs aprox. 35 kg.
The outside of the wall will have plywood and dry wall.

Inside the L will be a lower (85cm) stainless table and underneath this 2 wine fridges & a drinks fridge.

Space is very tight. '

I am exploring the idea of leaving the inside of the long part of the 'L' wall uncovered below the stainless worktop to use as part of my ventilation space for my appliances?

If this is crazy I'm happy to hear!
thank-you.

Comment: I don't believe that there's any requirement that the wall be paneled, but that's a matter of local code. Since you haven't told us where you are....

Comment: I’m in Italy, happy to receive any informative input.

Comment: @AranScutcher welcome to the site. I've submitted a request to the community team to [merge your accounts](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Please note that posting responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: It's your health codes you need to check, not building codes. The plan is mechanically sound. Cleanliness is likely to suffer though. I've cleared out enough bars to know that if whatever it is can get dirty or collect garbage, it *will be* absolutely gross. Out of sight, out of mind.